# Stream audio and video with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to stream an arbitrary file with `gstreamer`, I have the following command line but it does not work (I will use python when I get this to work)

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///tmp/File.mkv name=decoder name=decbin \
! queue\
! videoconvert ! x264enc \
! mp4mux name=muxer ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234 decbin. \
! queue \
! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! muxer.
```

and playing with

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc  port=1234 ! 'application/x-rtp,payload=96'\
! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! xvimagesink  sync=false
```

I know I have to add `rtph264pay` and `rtpmpapay` but I don't know where.